# Why do we have a differential term when taking the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For example, an area of a circle is $$A = \pi r^2$$

say we want to express a differential area ( a small area element) I am used to saying :
$$dA = 2\pi r dr $$

but why do we add this dr in the expression to the right? it is important but I was never taught why it is there.

Thank you.

Comment: It is informal notation for $\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dr} = 2\pi r$, i.e. that the derivative of the area with respect to the radius is $2\pi r$, i.e. that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{A(r+h)-A(r)}{h}=2\pi r$$ for all $r\in\mathbb R$ (while only $r>0$ is geometrically valid).

Comment: Why do you think the dA is there?  dr is there for the same reason.

Comment: My question is how did it come there. The first comment makes it clear.

Comment: You can think of $dA$ as a linear approximation to the change in area. If a circle has a radius $r$, and we increase it by a certain amount $dr$, then the change to area $\Delta A$ is given by
$$
\Delta A=\pi(r+dr)^2-\pi r^2=2\pi rdr+\pi (dr)^2 \, .
$$
Now, if $dr$ is very small, then $(dr)^2$ is smaller still, and so almost all of the change $\Delta A$ comes from the $2\pi r \, dr$ term, which is proportional to $dr$. Therefore, we can approximate $\Delta A$ as $2\pi r \, dr$. This approximation, $2\pi r \, dr$ is what we call $dA$.

Comment: Of course, this approximation isn't perfect—in this case, the error is $\pi(dr)^2$. However, notice that as $dr$ approaches $0$, this error also goes to $0$. In fact, not only does the error go to zero, it becomes tiny *relative to the size of* $dr$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{dr\to0}\frac{\Delta A-dA}{dr}=0 \, .
$$
More generally, if $A=f(r)$, then by definition $dA$ is a dependent variable that is proportional to the size of $dr$, which satisfies the above.

Comment: That is very eye opening. thank you for showing me this alternative approach as well.

Comment: No problem @realanswers! Let me know if you have any questions. By the way, if you want to notify someone when you comment, then you should insert @name into your comment. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for more details.